# Error en nginx + php7.2-fpm + Digital ocean +Ubuntu + laravel

Tags: php, ubuntu, digitalocean

He subido un proyecto a Digital ocean de laravel

En **LEMP**

pero tengo este error

```html
44 [crit] 16669#16669: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream
```

44 [crit] 16669#16669: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

he intentado hacer

[POSIBLE SOLUCION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470109/error-502-in-nginx-php5-fpm/10470827#10470827)

pero no se como acceder a las rutas que mencionan pues me salen blancos los documentos o en dado caso que no existe

así es como tengo mi archivo

```html
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

ese error hace que pase esto o eso es lo que creo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado acceder a :

```
nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

pero no me sale nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @aldanux no entiendo, debo de acceder a ese archivo no?. porque de ser así me muestra blanco.

Comment: Ok... que versión de ubuntu usas?

Comment: @aldanux Ubuntu LEMP on 18.04

Comment: @aldanux ya encuentro el archivo instale php7.2-fpm ahora si lo encuentro.. pero aún así hice las modiicaciones de la otra respuesta y no funciona.. pero al menos ahora ya me "Medio" carga algo pero aún así sigue saliendo erro de 404

Comment: @Shaz todavía persiste el problema :(

Comment: @Shaz el mismo,  me dice que la pagina no fue encontrada.

Comment: Acabé de instalar otro servidor lemp en DigitalOcean siguiendo sus guías y todo me funciona perfectamente, tardé menos de 15 minutos en dejar todo listo.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la siguiente configuración de nginx, es la que incluye Homestead (Máquina virtual creada para Laravel), solo estoy poniendo la sección relevante con el error que tienes:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

El problema está muy posiblemente en la primera parte:

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Ahí se intenta primero ubicar el archivo, luego un directorio y luego arrojar 404, mientras que en la nueva sintáxis, en tercer lugar se le pasa la solicitud al index.php de Laravel.